# A movie with two people running from a house to a boat; monster reaches one of them

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

This is a horror film from 70s or 80s.
All I remember is that a man and a woman are running away from a house toward a lake; the girl makes it to the boat, but the guy gets stuck in mud. He gradually sinks deeper until he sees a hand outstretched towards him - he looks up and it's a hideous monster. Suddenly he starts screaming while the girl witnesses this horror. She is in the boat, petrified, but the boat then rapidly capsizes. The movie kind of stops.